# Why do virtual machines become slower on high CPU usage?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu-usage

We run a a lot of virtual machines in a VMWare cluster, once the cpu is used for 80% things start to slow down.

Is there a logical reason for this? Also VMWare says it is using a lot of CPU (alert)

Comment: This makes total sea e each virtual machine is like its on application that requires a significant amount of CPU resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of virtualization like a movie. A movie is a series of individual frames, but played back the motion looks continuous.

It’s the same way with virtual machines. A physical CPU can only run one thing at a time, which means that only one virtual machine can run at a time. So the hypervisor “shares” a CPU by cutting up the CPU time into chunks. Each virtual machine gets a certain chunk to do its thing, and if it gets chunks of CPU often enough it’s like the movie:

It seems like the virtual machine has been running continuously, even when it hasn’t. Modern CPUs are fast enough that they can pull this illusion off.